# Increment Hex Values in bash Script

Tags: bash, hex

How do I increment a hex value by one and save it to a variable in a loop?

I have `echo 'obase=16;ibase=16;A+1' | bc`
This will output the correct hex value, but I can't seem to do the calculation with variable expansion.
I want to do something like `key=$(echo 'obase=16;ibase=16;$key+1' | bc)`, but this fails. I need to be able to increment from 0x0 to 0xffff and use the hex value, not just output it. Thanks!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191205/bash-base-conversion-from-decimal-to-hex

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
declare -i key

for (( key=0; key<=16#ff; key++ )); do
    printf "%d (dec) = %x (hex), " $key $key
    printf "%x (hex) + 1 = %x (hex)\n" $key $(( $key + 1))
done
```

Hope this helps.